# Invoke an HFArgumentParser based script from within a Click command

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, huggingface-transformers, python-click

I have a script `trainmodel.py` coming from an existing codebase (based on Hugginface ArgumentParsers) with almost 100 different arguments that is based on argparse. The script comes as a `main()` function that parses individually each argument, and when run with no arguments produces the entire help text.

I need to wrap this script coming from another codebase into my `Click` based CLI, but I have hard times figuring out a good way to wrap it. Specifically the my cli interface should inherit all the `trainmodel.py` accepted arguments and kind of replicate them within the Click cli subcommand.

Here is an example of `trainmodel.py`

```py
def main():
    parser = HfArgumentParser(
        (ModelArguments, DataTrainingArguments, TrainingArguments)
    )
    ... lot of code to train a deep learning model with almost 100 parameters
```

My existing CLI though needs to subclass the existing `main()` function into a group of arguments based on my existing library CLI group

```py
@click.command()
def my_train_model():
    from models.trainmodel import main
    main(*sys.argv[3:])
```

The command `train_model` is itself part of a click group from the outside `cli.py`

`cli.py`

```py
@click.group(name="model")
def model():
    pass

model.add_command(my_train_model)
cli.add_command(model)
```

For example, when I need to call the original script help, my interface with this call

```bash
mylibrary-cli model my-train-model --help
```

should pass the `--help` argument to the `trainmodel.main()` function and reproduce the arguments as from it.

How can I override the click interface and make the entire list of arguments be passed to the `trainmodel.py` script with the same help without manually copying all arguments inside my `click.command` decorated function `my_train_model`?
I would like to avoid hardcoding all the arguments accepted from `trainmodel.main()`.